# oracle e-business suit - financial error (compile flexfield segments)

Tags: oracle, erp

In oracle e-business suit to update ledger account it appears that error

> Error The descriptive flexfield with application name General Ledger
>   (SQLGL) and name Ledgers (GL_LEDGERS) is not compiled. Please contact
>   your system administrator.

recompile flex field segment
[image: z]

I have to fix it to update ledger account

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.  This question is about a software configuration problem in the Oracle e-Business Suite.

Comment: alright
but where could i ask about this application

Comment: If you have the Oracle e-Business Suite, you almost certainly have support. 
 So, search on http://support.oracle.com for your problem.  If that comes up empty, log an SR (service request).  Also, there are community forums accessible via support.oracle.com where you can post questions.

Comment: Yes, it does look like an EBS configuration issue. I did see this Oracle Support article at support.oracle.com, How to compile System Item flexfield? (Doc ID 2107792.1). The article pertains to inventory key flexfields (in lieu of GL).Perhaps the Oracle Forums might be better suited for this configuration question, https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-applications/e-business_suite/enterprise-resource-planning-erp/financials